# listview filtering specific value in vb

Tags: vb.net, listview

I want to filter a specific item in my listview in my vb program. My program work properly but what i want just to display the specific value in my vb. For example the value displayed in the txtbox is 1.1 but the listview is also displaying the value with 11.11 Please help me in this problem because i just want for my listview to display the 1.1 value only not 11.11

HERE IS MY CODE:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles txtFilter.TextChanged
    txtFilter.Text = "" & txtiket.Text & "." & txtiket.Text & ""
    Try
        Newdataset("SELECT `ticket_number`, `visit_PDF`, `Pdf_ID`, `Date_Upload` FROM `pdf_vicit_table` WHERE (Pdf_ID LIKE '%" & txtFilter.Text & "%') ORDER BY Pdf_ID ASC")
        If ds.Tables("a").Rows.Count < 0 Then
            ListView2.Items.Clear()
        Else
            ListView2.Items.Clear()
            For cnt = 0 To ds.Tables("a").Rows.Count - 1
                With ListView2.Items.Add(ds.Tables("a").Rows(cnt).ItemArray.GetValue(0).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("a").Rows(cnt).ItemArray.GetValue(1).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(ds.Tables("a").Rows(cnt).ItemArray.GetValue(2).ToString)
                    .SubItems.Add(Format(DateValue(ds.Tables("a").Rows(cnt).ItemArray.GetValue(3).ToString()), "yyyy-MM-dd"))
                End With
            Next
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question but you really ought to learn how to write a parameterised query.  As your code is, a malicious user could potentially delete everything in your database and even a non-malicious user could crash your app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has got exactly zero to do with your `ListView`.  Here's your database query:

```
Newdataset("SELECT `ticket_number`, `visit_PDF`, `Pdf_ID`, `Date_Upload` FROM  `pdf_vicit_table` WHERE (Pdf_ID LIKE '%" & txtFilter.Text & "%') ORDER BY Pdf_ID ASC")
```

You are SPECIFICALLY telling the database to give you any record where your `TextBox` value is contained anywhere in the `Pdf_ID`.  If what you actually want is only records where that column is equal to a specific value then say that, instead of saying that you want anything like the value.

```
Newdataset("SELECT `ticket_number`, `visit_PDF`, `Pdf_ID`, `Date_Upload` FROM  `pdf_vicit_table` WHERE (Pdf_ID = '" & txtFilter.Text & "') ORDER BY Pdf_ID ASC")
```

Comment: thank you verry much for the answer! My program is now working as it should be. thank you so much! how can i mark this question answered? HAHAHAH